# Running exe from commandline with parameter using c++

Tags: visual-c++, command-line-arguments

I am pretty new to this programming field and am stuck at a place.
This is wat i wanna do

I want to run an .exe from command line with parameters in Windows 7 through c++ and get the output produced by the command into the program.

the problem I am having is with changing the current directory of command prompt to the path of the exe and getting the output from the executed command into the program..

hope some one has ran into something such previously..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System function or ShellExecute function for running exe from command line with parameters using Cpp. You can read about System function [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4b6wz4t.aspx) and ShellExecute function [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As far as getting the output is concerned you can redirect the output to a file and read the file, or create pipes and redirect the output to pipe. You can provide the exe name along with the path so cd to directory wont be necessary, but I am not sure if its mandatory for you to run the exe from inside the same directory.